# Fingerprinting Windows Architecture from a file on remote system

Tags: fingerprinting, os-fingerprinting

This is a post following up with [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110673/how-to-find-windows-version-from-the-file-on-a-remote-system).

Similar situation as the above post - I'd like to know if there's a way to find out the architecture (x86 or x64) of a windows system from a file on a remote system. This is assuming I can only read files on a remote system and need to deduce from there.
I'd like to know for as many Windows versions as possible, but my specific use case is for Windows XP.

Comment: You have read access for the whole filesystem, or just part of it?

Comment: Whole filesystem. Just had a look at your answer - how silly! The Program files folder naming didn't even strike me! Also, Eula.txt I did have a look at. It gave me the OS version + SP information at the end, but not the architecture. Will try the others, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several hints, but the most obvious ones would be:

- On the current Windows versions the existence of `C:\Program Files (x86)\` tells it's a 64-bit system. Any 32-bit version doesn't have it.
- You could download `C:\Windows\System32\ntoskrnl.exe`. On it's version X.Y.Z the X.Y reveals the Windows (NT) version and Z the build. (5.0 for 2000, 5.1 for XP, 5.2 for 2003/XP64, 6.0 for Vista, 6.1 for 7, 6.2 for 8, 6.3 for 8.1 and 10.0 for 10).
- Such files as `System32\license.rtf`, `system32\eula.txt` or `C:\Windows\inf\layout.inf` might reveal the license version (Home, Pro etc.)